# How to make Intellij automatically parse custom beans?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, apache-camel

I'm working on a Java/Camel application. I've configured camel through XML files which leads to a

```
<camelContext id="CamelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <proxy id="someProcessor"
           serviceInterface="some.Processor"
           serviceUrl="direct:processMessage"/>
</camelContext>
```

Intellij always gives me a warning that the custom bean is not yet parsed. I don't want to agree on that for every edit I make in the CamelContext. E.g (changed the proxy id):

```
<camelContext id="CamelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <proxy id="someProcessor1"
           serviceInterface="some.Processor"
           serviceUrl="direct:processMessage"/>
</camelContext>
```

(BTW, if I reverse the edit, the bean is considered parsed again.)

Is there a way to automatically parse custom beans?

Comment: How are you triggering the warning for each edit? I just have to do alt-enter of the <camelContext> tag, select parse bean and that's it. I don't see the warning repeated

Comment: After parsing the bean like you said, the warning comes back after an edit in the context, see my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a `Spring Facet` and the Spring config file  including the *camelContext* is under the `Spring Application Context` then there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I checked under module settings, there is a spring facet which lists the (only) .xml configuration with the camel context.